# How to run headless Chrome on ubuntu terminal?

Tags: python, selenium, google-chrome, ubuntu

I'm new to ubuntu and web scraping with selenium. Recently I ran into problems in running my python web scraping scripts on a Ubuntu server. I accessed the ubuntu server remotely via my terminal.

When I tried to run the code on Ubuntu server but got the error below:

`selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: unknown error: Chrome failed to start: exited abnormally`
`(unknown error: DevToolsActivePort file doesn't exist)`
`(The process started from chrome location /usr/bin/google-chrome is no longer running, so ChromeDriver is assuming that Chrome has crashed.)`
`(Driver info: chromedriver=2.41.578700` `(2f1ed5f9343c13f73144538f15c00b370eda6706),platform=Linux 4.15.0-74-generic x86_64)`

I've already installed chrome, chrome driver and selenium on the server. When I checked the location of Chrome on the server, it returns:

`google-chrome: /usr/bin/google-chrome`

When I tried to run google chrome via `/usr/bin/google-chrome`, it returns the error below:

`~$ [0715/183414.382630:ERROR:nacl_helper_linux.cc(308)] NaCl helper process running without a sandbox!`
`Most likely you need to configure your SUID sandbox correctly`

I suppose the problem is there is no display for the browser? How can I solve this problem ?

Thank you very much.